# How to stop media player if external player(youtube,etc) is getting played

Tags: android, media-player

I have created an application to play audio using media player but my player does not stops even if other app like youtube starts playing video.

How to stop audio if other app starts playing an audio.

I have used mediaPlayer.start(); to play an audio.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to listen for Audio focus change.
Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html

OnAudioFocusChangeListener callback is called with a flag indicating audio focus status, which can be used to stop media player.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a AudioFocusChangeListener to listen for Audio focus change.

```
private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener;
audioFocusChangeListener =new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener()

{

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange ( int focusChange){
    switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            // Set volume level to desired levels
            play();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT:
            // You have audio focus for a short time
            play();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
            // Play over existing audio
            play();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            stop();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            // Temporary loss of audio focus expect to get it back you can keep your resources around
            pause();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // Lower the volume
            break;
    }
}
}

;
```